# Trouble with tree data structure in JavaFX

Tags: eclipse, javafx-2, scenebuilder

I am making a GUI for private purposes. The application first ask for login + pass, if correct   the main window appear. It exists of a menubar, textarea, webview and some basic buttons. When one of those buttons is clicked the webbrowser should appear but all the others elements should still be visible. So after an eventhandler:

```
    System.out.println("Stream");

StackPane root = new StackPane();
WebView VideoViewer = new WebView();
WebEngine engine = VideoViewer.getEngine();
engine.load("http://www.oracle.com/products/index.html");
root.getChildren().add(VideoViewer);

Scene scene = new Scene(root);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();

System.out.println("Streaming...");
```

As you can see whole windows is filled with the html-page, my question is:

- How can I update the WebView without replacing the whole content of my stage?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to use the SceneBuilder program to design the UI?  If not, remove the tag because answers will be different.

Comment: @brian: Yes I am indeed using SceneBuilder, sorry for not mentioning

Comment: You tagged it scenebuilder but the code doesn't look like it.  If you have an fxml file, post it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`BorderPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) instead of the StackPane.  A StackPane 'stacks' everything on top of each other.  The BorderPane allows you to pick a side for each control element.  If you have many elements for one side, put them in a VBox or HBox.

Comment: Good point didn't think of it earlier. Tried it but I get a complete blank. I'll keep you updated. Thanks!